# get old data of tf

Tags: ros, data, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ros-users,
is there a way of access old data of tf? I mean, when I lookup for a transform, I need the latest data together with second to last, third to last..
I'm working with tf on ros fuerte
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185546/get-old-data-of-tf/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-08**:
Do you need the last/second to last, etc. in an index or time basis? If index-based: Why?

**Comment by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on 2014-07-08**:\

- in an index basis
- because, if I understood correctly, on time based the given data is an interpolation of two values. Instead, I would like to know if there is access to the actual values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get in and instrument or access the interior storage by index. However it's not well defined as soon as you have more than one link in your span. If you need that sort of specific data I'd suggest that you generate and store it yourself.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1